# CSV file not found [but it really there]

Tags: node.js, csv

So guys, i basically just want to read my .csv file. My file look like this:

```
name, phone, address
"test", "123", "city name"
```

so i use Node.Js env to read that out, here's my code

```
const fs = require('fs')

const csv_file = fs.readFileSync('test.csv', 'utf-8')

console.log(csv_file)
```

but i always get this error:

```
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'test.csv'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:394:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/lucky/2CF204AFF2047EF8/lucky/project/himatro-web-app/dokumentasi/data/reader.js:4:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'test.csv'
```

i really really sure i'm not misspell anything, because my directory for my reader file is exactly the same with my csv file. even when i use cat command, i can read my file out.

i tried different approach using this code:

```
const csv = require('csv-parse')
const fs = require('fs')
const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('Password.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log(results);
  });
```

but the error is exactly the same. I couldn't find the solution anywhere, almost spent 1 hour just because this seemingly litle problem. Do you guys have any solution? each would be much apreciated

Comment: where do you have the file? at the root level of the project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path using the path module

```
const fs = require("fs");
// here is where you add the pathname 
const filePath = require("path").resolve(__dirname, "./test.csv");
const csv_file = fs.readFileSync(filePath,'utf-8');
console.log("csv_file", csv_file);
```